# Is there anyway to completely hide Android window in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Sorry I've been looking for a while. I need to maximize window space and since I already have a different window for the logcat the Android window is very redundant. The problem is, even if I choose to hide the window, everytime I run the app it pops up again. It's very disruptive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

1. Change it to a floating window so you can place it where you want.
2. Update your run configuration, under the logcat tab deselect "Show logcat automatically"

Comment: There we go! I think that's what I needed.